# Captcha recaptcha does not validate

Tags: php, validation, form-submit, captcha, recaptcha

I have followed google tutorial for Captcha.

I have added the libraries. It shows on the site, however it when I fill the form and leave don't touch the recaptcha form it stills send, when its not suppose to.

This is the main code from google:

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');

// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "i have added the key here";
$privatekey = "i have added the key here";
# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

# was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if ($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]) {
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if ($resp->is_valid) {
            echo "You got it!";
    } else {
            # set the error code so that we can display it
            $error = $resp->error;
    }
}
 echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
```

I was thinking maybe it's in the wrong place. The private key is correct.

The site is:

http://www.the-big-bbq.co.uk/invitation.php#prettyPhoto

Answer (score 0):

make sure you update keys (following variables) in "recaptchalib.php"

define("PUBKEY", "");
define("PRIKEY", "");

Comment: i have added them both, but now i get the error: To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create ..

Comment: define("PUBKEY", "your key goes here"); define("PRIKEY", "your key goes here"); replace keys with "your key goes here". Dont make it blank

Comment: iv added it:  if ($privkey == null || $privkey == 'xxxx') { still not working